# Different resuls when multiplying

Tags: java, operators, range

I have the following code and output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long lon = 1000;
    lon = lon * 3600;
    lon = lon * 24;
    lon = lon * 365;

    System.out.println("lon:  " + lon);

    long lon2 = 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 365;
    System.out.println("lon2: " + lon2);
}
lon:  31536000000
lon2: 1471228928
```

I guess some kind of overflow is occurring with `lon2`, but I can't seem to figure it out. The result is way below Long.MAX_VALUE. Any idea?

Comment: The calculation of lon2 is done on the right-hand-side in 32-bit int arithmetic. It therefore overflows at 2^32 - 1 rather than at 2^64 - 1. Cast operands to (long) to avoid this overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java isn't smart enough to guess your intent here.

Your problem is that you're multiplying *`int`s* where overflow occurs. Every number in that calculation is an `int`, so the result of it is also an `int`. On assignment the resulting `int` is converted to `long`, but by then it's too late.

So use something like

```
long lon2 = 1000L * 3600 * 24 * 365;
```

to make sure the whole calculation is done in `long`s. Or, to be safe, just affix the `L` on every literal there. Makes your intent very clear :-)